# Clicking on the options of an active filter does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a filter like the one [here](https://codepen.io/noel82/pen/aOVPLB?fbclid=IwAR2wJlFrel03D1ON0hN0cB7tJTefY75CNnd4F4eCWWB5yd7yCSC0Va52zkc).

I have written some code in an HTML file and the aspect is identical, but the JavaScript does not work, meaning that if I click on a different option that the one active by default then nothing happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#filter-bar li").click(function() {
    $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target"));
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#filter-bar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#wrapper-filter {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 570px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar li {
  width: 190px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.pill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #39c;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #444;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filter-option {
  transition: color 500ms;
}

#filter-bar.option-1 .pill {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-2 .pill {
  margin-left: 187px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-3 .pill {
  margin-left: 380px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

.option-1.active,
.option-2.active,
.option-3.active {
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Animated filter selector</h2>

<div id="wrapper-filter">

  <ul id="filter-bar">
    <span class="pill"></span>
    <li class="filter-option option-1 active" data-target="option-1">Books</li>
    <li class="filter-option option-2" data-target="option-2">Shoes</li>
    <li class="filter-option option-3" data-target="option-3">Toys</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

So, what I think is that the Javascript script is not visible at all, so what it should do, does not happen at all.
Did I place it wrongly? I am a front-end beginner, so I am not sure what is wrong.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just missed adding jQuery, add this to the head section in your html file `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This will add the jQuery library to your project, jQuery will add a bunch of new features. Take a look at the docs [here](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter-bar li").click(function() {
    $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target"));
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#filter-bar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#wrapper-filter {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 570px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar li {
  width: 190px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.pill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #39c;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #444;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filter-option {
  transition: color 500ms;
}

#filter-bar.option-1 .pill {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-2 .pill {
  margin-left: 187px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.option-3 .pill {
  margin-left: 380px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

.option-1.active,
.option-2.active,
.option-3.active {
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Animated filter selector</h2>
  <div id="wrapper-filter">
    <ul id="filter-bar">
      <span class="pill"></span>
      <li class="filter-option option-1 active" data-target="option-1">Books</li>
      <li class="filter-option option-2" data-target="option-2">Shoes</li>
      <li class="filter-option option-3" data-target="option-3">Toys</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```